# How to add a range of separate images to VSE without merging them in one video strip?

Tags: video-sequence-editor, image

I press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, choose image, then I see the menu for browsing images. So if I select several pictures and add them, Blender will join them in one video-stripe, but I want to avoid that. I want to add a range of separate images at a time to work with them in the VSE.

Answer (score 4):

Add images as usual strip and then use *Separate Images* to make each image as separate strip.

From [manual](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/sequencer/usage.html#separate-images-to-strips):

> <kbd>Y</kbd> Converts the strip into multiple strips, one strip for each frame. Very useful for slide shows and other cases where you want to bring in a set on non-continuous images.

With strip selected press <kbd>Y</kbd> (or open *Strip* > *Separate Images*) and choose how long (in frames) each resulting strip should be.

[image: screenshot of VSE separating imgs]
[image: screenshot of VSE separating imgs - proceeding]

Then you can grab resulting strips as desired.

Comment: Yes, it is exactly what I need. Success! :D

But I still remember that there was a way to add images separately. My goal is reached, thanks a lot, Mr Zak! 
It is only for interest to find that way as it is faster.